# Burning a CD programmatically

Tags: c, windows, cd-burning

How can I write something onto a CD using ANSI C working under Windows?

Comment: Why wouldn't that be a real question? I tried to fix the grammar somewhat. I don't see a reason to close this question at all.

Comment: This could help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82993/windows-cd-burning-api

Answer (score 3):

IMAPI is the way Microsoft normally recommends. There are various other libraries available as well, but you have to pay for most of them.