# Burn files to CD using c#

Tags: c#, windows-7, cd-burning

I am writing a program that downloads images to the hard drive and then I want to burn the folders that those are all divided up into, on a cd.  I don't want to create and image to burn, I just want to take all those folders and files and burn them to disc just like they are on the hard drive.  Anyone know of a way to do this in C#?

I am using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMAPI2 - version 2 of the IMAPI API - is native to Windows 7 and is the preferred interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366457(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do this without calling API calls in to windows. It appears to be done with COM calls([ICDBurn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for XP, [MAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows Vista or newer). [Here is a SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82993/windows-cd-burning-api) that can point you in the right direction in how to do it in C++.

If you need assistance doing COM calls in C# feel free to open a new question on the issue you are having with that.

Answer (score 4):

As of Windows Vista you can use the [IMAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. This API enables you to burn images to CD, DVD and Blu-ray.

More information about the Image Master API can of course be found on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366450(v=VS.85).aspx

Check out this CodeProject article which talks in detail about it:

Another third party library that can help is [SharpRecorder](http://code.google.com/p/sharprecorder/). The code is hosted on Google. Take a look at is to see if it fits your requirements. If not, you can always access the code and see how it works and learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of ways to do this with C# and IMAP2 Here is an example on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24544/Burning-and-Erasing-CD-DVD-Blu-ray-Media-with-C-an)

Also there is another example [here](http://www.gangleri.net/2010/03/02/BurningFilesToCDDVDWithCAndWindowsXP.aspx) using c#

note: if you are doing this on 7 you will need this [update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932716)