# How to interact with CDs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cd-rom

I know python pretty well as a language but I only know a small portion of the massive standard library and I just realized I have absolutely no idea how I would read or write to a CD in Python, let alone any other language. I imagine the file reading/writing methods must come into play, but I feel like surely it must be somehow different.

How would I read or write to a CD in Python? Are there any special practices that are generally observed for this, as opposed to reading/writing to hard drive?

Is it as simple as navigating to the path of the CD drive and treating it exactly the same as a normal drive?

I suppose CDs are really becoming antiquated and this knowledge will soon pass out of usefulness, but I'm still interested in it.

Comment: What OS are you using? In UNIX-like systems, *reading* is as easy as reading `/dev/cd0` (or whatever device name your OS uses).

Comment: I'm on Windows, but I'm sure there isn't a separate interface for each OS...

Comment: Reading is exactly like reading any other file.  Writing is definitely OS specific.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11194299/10396 for references to the windows API you need.