# Is it possible to burn CD/DVD using Mastered Disc Format (i.e. Windows-7 default feature) in C#.net?

Tags: c#, c++, cd, dvd-burning, cd-burning

Is it possible to burn CD/DVD using Window's-7 CD/DVD player method.(i.e. using Mastered Disc Format) in C#.net? 
Because if i burn disc with mastered format, it will work on most computers. 
Cd burning process feature is provided by Windows 7. 
I want to use windows 7 default feature to burn CD with Mastered format to call this process using C#.net(4.0 framework).

Please consider this --- I don't want to use IMAPI(any version) dlls or any 3rd party tool in my C#.net application.
I just want to use default Windows API to call for CD burning process in C#.net.

Please suggests me if anyone know. 
Will be appreciated.

Comment: Too broad question. Write some code and if you get some with a specific issue then come back here for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Burn files to CD using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194299/burn-files-to-cd-using-c-sharp)

Comment: _"I want to use windows 7 default feature"_ - what makes you think Windows itself doesn't call into its own (extended) APIs (i.e. IMAPI)?